# To Create re-usable java script code

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, bootstrap-4

[Form sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6u9e.png),[Error sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nishl.png) My Scenario is when clicking ADD VEHICLE button means it will generate new input boxes,i tried to reuse a same java script to generate the input text boxes,i 
tried using ID,

```
   var wrapper         = $("#vehiclegroupid"); //Fields wrapper
   var add_button      = $("#addvehicleBtnid"); //Add button ID
```

it will supports only for the particular place,

if i tried to use class name

```
 var wrapper         = $(".summa"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button      = $(".summa2"); //Add button ID
```

it will disturbs other related components..Here is sources

HTML

```
<!-- Two Wheeler -->
<div class="form-group" id="vehiclegroup">
<label for="vehicleid">Add Two Wheeler(s) Details</label>
<div id="vehiclegroupid" class="summa"></div>
<input type="button" id="addvehicleBtnid" value="Add Vehicle" class="form-control col-md-2 summa2"></input>
</div>

<!-- Four Wheeler -->
<div class="form-group" id="fourvehiclegroup">
<label for="vehicleid">Add Four Wheeler(s) Details</label>
<div id="vehiclegroupid2" class="summa"></div>
<input type="button" id="addvehicleBtnid2" value="Add Vehicle" class="form-control col-md-2 summa2"></input>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
/**
 * This is especially for adding input fields for entering co-owner details
 */

$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
   // var wrapper         = $("#vehiclegroupid","#vehiclegroupid2"); //Fields wrapper
  //  var add_button      = $("#addvehicleBtnid","#addvehicleBtnid2"); //Add button ID
  var wrapper         = $(".summa"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button      = $(".summa2"); //Add button ID
    var x = 0; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment now x=1 after x++ x=2,so next code 2%2==0 is true


        $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-row">'          
                +'<!-- Vehicle Name -->'
                +'<div id="TextBoxDiv'+x+'" class="form-group col-md-4">'
                +'<label for="cowner'+x+'">Vehicle Name</label>'
                +'<input id="cowner'+x+'" type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name"></input>'
                +'</div>'

                +'<!-- Vehicle Registration Number -->'
                +'<div class="form-group col-md-4">'
                +'<label for="oph'+x+'">Vehicle Registration Number</label>'
                +'<input id="oph'+x+'" type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex (TN 99 AD 9999)"></input>'
                +'</div>'


                    +'<a href="#"class="remove_field col-md-1"> X </a>'
                    +'</div>');

        }
        else{
            alert("Sorry..!You Cannot Add More Than 5 Vehicles");
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

Please help me to make reusable script code...Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually asking here.  If your selector doesn't target the elements you want, use one that does.  And I suspect you wanted to put the comma *inside* the selector in your first examples.

Comment: My Scenario is when clicking ADD VEHICLE button (for Two Wheeler and Four Wheeler) means it will generate new input boxes,i tried to reuse a same java script to generate the input text boxes,

Comment: You're going to have to clarify the problem.  "Create re-usable code" isn't a question.  In what specific way does your code not work as intended?  When you debug, how does it fail?

Comment: i added Image links at the starting of the post..please refer..Thank You

Comment: i am using same class name to call the javascript for 2 components like 2wheeler and 4wheeler,when i clicking 2 wheeler it will generate input boxes for 2 wheeler only but here it will generate input boxes for 4 wheeler also..please refer image samples..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, what you have is a repeated group of elements which includes a button and you're attempting to have a single click handler which, when clicking a button, it affects *only* that local group and not all of the repeated groups.

You can achieve this by combining your selectors with some DOM traversal.  You can still have a single handler, it just needs to more specifically identify the target based on what was clicked.

Currently your logic within your handler is:

> Find all matching `.summa` elements.  Append the new HTML.

Instead, you want this:

> From `this`, find the nearest `.summa` element.  Append the new HTML.

`this` of course is the button which was clicked.  One way to find the "nearest" in this case is to traverse up to the closest common parent element and then find the target element within that.

Something like this:

```
$('.summa2').click(function(e){
    var wrapper = $(this).closest('div.form-group').find('.summa');

    // the rest of your click handler code
});
```

So starting from `this` (which is the button that gets clicked) the selector traverses "up" to the closest `div.form-group` (which is the overall repeated container) and then traverses back "down" to the target `.summa` (which is the target `div` within that group).

---

**Update:** And, of course, since your later click handler was relying on the `wrapper` variable it can now no longer do that.  Just use the selector directly instead of the variable:

```
$('.summa').on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
})
```

Comment: Hello David,Thanks for your help..But when i clicking close Button ,it is not responding..see the code snipet  
      $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on 
      remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })

Comment: @VigneshR: When are you trying to bind that click event?  What is `wrapper` when that happens?  This sounds like a separate problem.

Comment: jQuery.Deferred exception: wrapper is not defined @http://localhost:8080/js/AddVehicles.js:40:5
j@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2:30201
g/</k<@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2:30517

Comment: @VigneshR: In your original code `wrapper` was defined outside of your click handler, now it's defined inside (because it needs to be defined dynamically).  So you need to change anything else that might rely on it.  In this case it *looks like* you just need to replace the variable name with the selector: `".summa2"`.

Comment: Scenario is when clicking ADD button it will generate VEHICLE NAME,VEHICLE NUMBER and X (Close link),When we need to remove the  input details means the X (close) is needed so that is mentioned in my java script code please refer the complete script in this post..Thank You

Comment: @VigneshR: Refer to the updated answer.  You simply need to use the actual selector instead of the variable, since the variable no longer exists in that scope.